# It seems I can remove my locked downvote of a question after retagging?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, down-votes, locked-votes

Today I downvoted one question and later I changed my mind but it was too late. Then I realized that there was one tag missing (array), so I retagged with my privileges and it was possible to remove my downvote... is it supposed to work like this or there is a crack there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Votes are only locked until the post is edited.

If an OP edits their post, we want those who originally voted to be able to go back and change their votes, if their concerns have been addressed.

Comment: This is strange... retagging should not be considered an edit... I did not change the question at all.

Comment: @sgcastro Recently, the retag button was removed, and consolidated into the edit button. This is potentially an artifact of that - while you're technically still retagging, the system logs an edit action, and so unlocks the votes.

Comment: Couldn't the system log, edit the tag, but with a flag that it was just a retag action, keeping the vote locked since it was not really editted?

Comment: Another thing... my name stays there as if I had really editted the question, when actually I had just retagged...

Comment: @sgcastro Also an artifact of the removal of retagging. Perhaps it should not be this way - but that's more of a feature request than a bug report :P

Comment: @SaulloCastro question consists of three parts: title, body, and tags. Changing any of those means editing the question. I'm pretty sure that even when retag was alive doing it "unlocked" the votes. Even a rollback is considered an edit as far as I can tell... editing back to previous revision.